# IE8 Out of memory and "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid for a website i am developing and can't seem to find the problems in ie8. In ff everything works fine, but in ie8 i get the "Out of memory at line 12" message followed by a list of "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Here is the list with all the js files i include:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.jstree.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 <script src="js/src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/src/grid.jqueryui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Do you know what can cause this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that `pathtojsfiles` inside of `grid.loader.js` point to the correct path (like `js/src` in your case). See [Development Installation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install#development_installation) part of the jqGrid documentation for details.